# How to find the printer type in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

how can I find the printer type which is installed in our PC, whether is it dot-Matrix, laser or inkjet in c#?

Comment: sorry, here how can i find the installed printer is dotmatrix or not ..

Comment: my requirememnt is i have 12 printers each of different company. 3 dotmatrix ,4 laser and rest 5 inkject i need to print it to dotmatrix , with out giving the name of the printer we need to identify the printer is dotmatrix?

Comment: Using WMI Win32_Printer and read this part "MarkingTechnology" : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394363(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following class gives you whether the printer is dot-Matrix, laser or inkjet:

```
using System;
using System.Management;

namespace ConsoleDemo
{
class Printer
{
 public enum TechnologyType
    {
        Other = 1,
        Unknown = 2,
        Electrophotographic_LED = 3,
        Electrophotographic_Laser = 4,
        Electrophotographic_Other = 5,
        Impact_Moving_Head_Dot_Matrix_9pin = 6,
        Impact_Moving_Head_Dot_Matrix_24pin = 7,
        Impact_Moving_Head_Dot_Matrix_Other = 8,
        Impact_Moving_Head_Fully_Formed = 9,
        Impact_Band = 10,
        Impact_Other = 11,
        Inkjet_Aqueous = 12,
        Inkjet_Solid = 13,
        Inkjet_Other = 14,
        Pen_ = 15,
        Thermal_Transfer = 16,
        Thermal_Sensitive = 17,
        Thermal_Diffusion = 18,
        Thermal_Other = 19,
        Electroerosion = 20,
        Electrostatic = 21,
        Photographic_Microfiche = 22,
        Photographic_Imagesetter = 23,
        Photographic_Other = 24,
        Ion_Deposition = 25,
        eBeam = 26,
        Typesetter = 27
    }
    
    public static void GetPrinterInfo()
    {
        var printerQuery = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * from Win32_Printer");
        foreach (var printer in printerQuery.Get())
        {
            var name = printer.GetPropertyValue("Name");
            var status = printer.GetPropertyValue("Status");
            var isDefault = printer.GetPropertyValue("Description");
            var MarkingTechnology = printer.GetPropertyValue("MarkingTechnology");
           var CurrentCapabilities = (string )printer.GetPropertyValue("CurrentCapabilities");
            Console.WriteLine("Name:{0} |(Status: {1} | Description: {2}| Technology: {3} | {4} ",
                name, status, isDefault, MarkingTechnology , CurrentCapabilities);
        }
    }

}
```

}

The enum TechnologyType gives you the type of printer technology.

For more information review: [Win32_Printer class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394363(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: var MarkingTechnology = printer.GetPropertyValue("MarkingTechnology");
           var CurrentCapabilities = (string )printer.GetPropertyValue("CurrentCapabilities"); this two always showing null

Comment: It probably that the installed device driver of the  printer doesn't support returning these information.
Can you check CurrentLanguage?. You can find values like Epson (11)