# C++: Is there a way to programmatically check if my printer is an Inkjet or a Laser printer?

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++-2008

I'm writing a program to display the type of printer connected to the system with it's other details, but i can't seem to find any function, method or class that gives me the details on the printer's type(i.e: if it's an inkjet or a laser printer). Any suggestions at to how to do it will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Did you look into the Windows printer APIs? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/printdocs/printdocs-printing

Comment: This kind of info is exposed through WMI, you want to query [Win32_Printer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-printer).

Comment: i was able to find it in Win32_Printer class under MarkingTechnology, but when i run the WMIC command to check it it showed me no value. The command i used was **"wmic printer get MarkingTechnology, name"**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38419905/10611792. It probably that the installed device driver of the printer doesn't support returning these information.

Comment: Are there any printers with the drivers that support these return values?

Answer (score 0):

So, as far as my research took me there is definitive no way to do this. This doesn't work because the printer drivers aren't equipped to return those values as stated by @Drake Wu - MSTF. So I have decided to build a database of the information I required and use that.

Answer (score -2):

Please check [GetPrinter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/printdocs/getprinter?redirectedfrom=MSDN) MS SDK API and see `pPrinter` and other similar APIs at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/printdocs/printing-and-print-spooler-functions#printer-functions

Comment: GetPrinter can return 9 different data structures. Which of them contains the printer type?

Comment: already mentioned "pPrinter" and it require some more debugging, I have done it in past but don't have handy code.

Comment: @mkag "pPrinter" isn't a structure in the printer spool API. Do you know which of the structures contains the information i'm looking for from **PRINTER_INFO_1 - PRINTER_INFO_9**?

Comment: I also extracted it from some of the PRINTER_INFO_? structure but not able to recall code.