# The command "wmic printer get MarkingTechnology" doesn't show me any value

Tags: winapi, wmic, printers

I'm trying to get details on the marking technology my printer uses but upon running the "wmic printer get MarkingTechnology" command i just get a blank screen here's a picture of the [command prompt displaying the command after being run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ItQU.png)

Comment: What details are you expect to get?

Comment: I expected to get the what type of printer it was, like if it was an inkjet or laser printer. That sort of information.

Comment: I noticed that you have a similar problem on another post, and there is a workable [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38419463/how-to-find-the-printer-type-in-c/38419905#38419905) in the comments, and this is not just a matter of using the WMI command to get the printer to be inkjet or laser printed.Is this method effective for you?

Comment: I tried the solution provided but it returns Null. The same problem the OP of that question faced. So now i'm looking to find if the majority of printer drivers return Null for the same or if it's just a small number of printers with the drivers that return Null.

Comment: I was unable to find a solution and i cannot ask the one who provided the solution(@M.Hassan) what to do further is there any way you can help me @StriveSun-MSFT? any help is greatly appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this source [***How to get model of printer with POWERSHELL?***](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/fr-FR/189a395c-0e5a-4553-948e-849bc08dd63a/how-to-get-model-of-printer-with-powershell?forum=winserverprint) can help you or not ?

```
get-wmiobject win32_printer -ComputerName localhost
```

or

```
get-wmiobject win32_printer | ft
get-wmiobject win32_printer | ?{$_.ShareName -eq "Printer01"} | fl *
get-wmiobject win32_printer | ft Name,ShareName,DriverName -Autosize
```

Comment: sadly It appears that the printer drivers are not equipped to return the values i need